# Import a module for local development

Tags: javascript, import, module, es6-modules

I would like to import a module (threejs in my case) in my javascript file in order to have the autocomplete function of vscode working. When I use

```
import * as THREE from './lib/three'
```

at the top of my working js file, the autocomplete functionality will work,
[image: autocomplete]

but the import actually is blocked by CORS cross-origin policy, saying that the same origin rule permits reading from external source files (reason the request was not http ?!).

Does anyone know a workaround to this? So far I have only been able to use the module without an import statement and have accordingly not been able to use the autocomplete functionality.

This is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
    <script type="module" src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And sketch.js

```
import * as THREE from './lib/three';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.
Fonzane

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `type="module"` in your script tag `<script src="sketch.js" type="module"></script>`

You can read up on js modules here: https://appdividend.com/2019/01/23/javascript-import-statement-tutorial-with-example/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Now when I try to open the html file via explorer I get a CORS same-origin error (saying the cors-request was not http), and when I try to open the html via a simple local http-server I get the error message that loading the module failed cause of an unsupported mime-type (""). Is the latter error specific to three.js?

Comment: You need to see which request is failing. A bit more info would be nice.

Comment: It's not an actual request (the network tab is empty) but it is saying that reading of an external resource is blocked by CORS-Policy due to cross-origin.